# how to get weekly. quarterly and monthly count from a daily data set of a year

Tags: r, dplyr

I ave data yearly set with daily login data of 4440 employee. i wan to get the weekly, quarterly insight and monthly insights, but i am not bale to understand how do i get this count in R. i have 4400 rows and 256 columns.`enter code here`

> dput(new_emp_intime [1:2, ])
>   structure(list(X05.01.15 = structure(c(-62008141528, -62008140748
>   ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.01.15 = structure(c(-61976606368, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X07.01.15 = structure(c(-61945071568, 
>   -61945070908), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X08.01.15 = structure(c(-61913534548, 
>   -61913533468), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.01.15 = structure(c(-61881911068, 
>   -61881912628), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X12.01.15 = structure(c(-61787304688, 
>   -61787303608), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.01.15 = structure(c(-61755680428, 
>   -61755678628), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X15.01.15 = structure(c(-61692609148, 
>   -61692610588), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.01.15 = structure(c(-61661072068, 
>   -61661073388), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X19.01.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61566377428), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.01.15 = structure(c(-61534843408, 
>   -61534844668), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X21.01.15 = structure(c(-61503221068, 
>   -61503221248), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X22.01.15 = structure(c(-61471685188, 
>   -61471684228), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.01.15 = structure(c(-61440150628, 
>   -61440150808), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.01.15 = structure(c(-61313918608, 
>   -61313917588), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X28.01.15 = structure(c(-61282382248, 
>   -61282381528), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X29.01.15 = structure(c(-61250760028, 
>   -61250760088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.01.15 = structure(c(-61219223068, 
>   -61219224268), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X02.02.15 = structure(c(-62100159328, 
>   -62100157588), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.02.15 = structure(c(-62068620628, 
>   -62068622308), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X04.02.15 = structure(c(-62037086728, 
>   -62037084508), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X05.02.15 = structure(c(-62005464088, 
>   -62005463308), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.02.15 = structure(c(-61973928028, 
>   -61973930488), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.02.15 = structure(c(-61879233148, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X10.02.15 = structure(c(-61847696368, 
>   -61847696608), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X11.02.15 = structure(c(-61816160128, 
>   -61816162408), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X12.02.15 = structure(c(-61784624608, 
>   -61784624608), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.02.15 = structure(c(-61753005628, 
>   -61753004308), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.02.15 = structure(c(-61658393968, 
>   -61658394568), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X17.02.15 = structure(c(-61626772228, 
>   -61626773308), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X18.02.15 = structure(c(-61595235028, 
>   -61595236768), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X19.02.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61563699748), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.02.15 = structure(c(-61532164768, 
>   -61532164048), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.02.15 = structure(c(-61437470848, 
>   -61437471148), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.02.15 = structure(c(-61405933348, 
>   -61405934968), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X25.02.15 = structure(c(-61374312088, 
>   -61374311728), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X26.02.15 = structure(c(-61342775848, 
>   -61342775668), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.02.15 = structure(c(-61311239728, 
>   -61311237748), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X02.03.15 = structure(c(-62097737668, 
>   -62097739108), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.03.15 = structure(c(-62066202328, 
>   -62066200948), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X04.03.15 = structure(c(-62034580108, 
>   -62034580648), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.03.15 = structure(c(-61971508708, 
>   -61971508348), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.03.15 = structure(c(-61876812328, 
>   -61876813888), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X10.03.15 = structure(c(-61845278788, 
>   -61845279688), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X11.03.15 = structure(c(-61813742728, 
>   -61813742188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X12.03.15 = structure(c(-61782119008, 
>   -61782119668), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.03.15 = structure(c(-61750583188, 
>   -61750583668), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.03.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61655889448), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X17.03.15 = structure(c(-61624352908, 
>   -61624354648), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X18.03.15 = structure(c(-61592815528, 
>   -61592817208), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X19.03.15 = structure(c(-61561281148, 
>   -61561282048), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.03.15 = structure(c(-61529656588, 
>   -61529658448), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.03.15 = structure(c(-61435050148, 
>   -61435050688), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.03.15 = structure(c(-61403426428, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X25.03.15 = structure(c(-61371893548, 
>   -61371892228), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X26.03.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61340356888), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.03.15 = structure(c(-61308821188, 
>   -61308820288), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.03.15 = structure(c(-61214125348, 
>   -61214125768), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X31.03.15 = structure(c(-61182589528, 
>   -61182588208), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X01.04.15 = structure(c(-62126595688, 
>   -62126597248), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X02.04.15 = structure(c(-62095061308, 
>   -62095060828), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.04.15 = structure(c(-62063524408, 
>   -62063522608), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.04.15 = structure(c(-61968831208, 
>   -61968828928), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X07.04.15 = structure(c(-61937293048, 
>   -61937292688), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X08.04.15 = structure(c(-61905671368, 
>   -61905672448), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.04.15 = structure(c(-61874137948, 
>   -61874135488), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X10.04.15 = structure(c(-61842600448, 
>   -61842600388), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.04.15 = structure(c(-61747906468, 
>   -61747906828), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X14.04.15 = structure(c(-61716369328, 
>   -61716369808), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X15.04.15 = structure(c(-61684833508, 
>   -61684832848), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.04.15 = structure(c(-61653211648, 
>   -61653210388), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X17.04.15 = structure(c(-61621675168, 
>   -61621676008), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.04.15 = structure(c(-61526980228, 
>   -61526980168), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X21.04.15 = structure(c(-61495445008, 
>   -61495443148), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X22.04.15 = structure(c(-61463908648, 
>   -61463909608), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.04.15 = structure(c(-61432371688, 
>   -61432372048), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.04.15 = structure(c(-61400749708, 
>   -61400749408), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.04.15 = structure(c(-61306141288, 
>   -61306143628), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X28.04.15 = structure(c(-61274519788, 
>   -61274520088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X29.04.15 = structure(c(-61242984448, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.04.15 = structure(c(-61211448328, 
>   -61211446768), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X04.05.15 = structure(c(-62029311208, 
>   -62029310428), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X05.05.15 = structure(c(-61997774368, 
>   -61997772508), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.05.15 = structure(c(-61966238668, 
>   -61966238848), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X07.05.15 = structure(c(-61934701648, 
>   -61934702668), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X08.05.15 = structure(c(-61903079908, 
>   -61903079848), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X11.05.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61808471728), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X12.05.15 = structure(c(-61776849808, 
>   -61776850168), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.05.15 = structure(c(-61745311768, 
>   -61745312848), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X14.05.15 = structure(c(-61713777808, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X15.05.15 = structure(c(-61682241508, 
>   -61682242228), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X18.05.15 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
>   NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X19.05.15 = structure(c(-61556011468, 
>   -61556011528), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.05.15 = structure(c(-61524388408, 
>   -61524387328), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X21.05.15 = structure(c(-61492852828, 
>   -61492853488), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X22.05.15 = structure(c(-61461315268, 
>   -61461314188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X25.05.15 = structure(c(-61366621108, 
>   -61366622848), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X26.05.15 = structure(c(-61335084988, 
>   -61335087088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.05.15 = structure(c(-61303551148, 
>   -61303550428), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X28.05.15 = structure(c(-61271927788, 
>   -61271927968), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X29.05.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61240392088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X01.06.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -62121326368), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X02.06.15 = structure(c(-62089788808, 
>   -62089790188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.06.15 = structure(c(-62058254788, 
>   -62058253408), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X04.06.15 = structure(c(-62026630228, 
>   -62026633348), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X05.06.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61995095248), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X08.06.15 = structure(c(-61900400188, 
>   -61900402108), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.06.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61868865268), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X10.06.15 = structure(c(-61837329568, 
>   -61837330468), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X11.06.15 = structure(c(-61805793988, 
>   -61805793508), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X12.06.15 = structure(c(-61774170028, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X15.06.15 = structure(c(-61679563408, 
>   -61679563708), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.06.15 = structure(c(-61647940468, 
>   -61647939508), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X17.06.15 = structure(c(-61616405248, 
>   -61616404888), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X18.06.15 = structure(c(-61584868228, 
>   -61584868708), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X19.06.15 = structure(c(-61553332048, 
>   -61553331628), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X22.06.15 = structure(c(-61458638728, 
>   -61458638728), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.06.15 = structure(c(-61427102248, 
>   -61427102068), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.06.15 = structure(c(-61395479668, 
>   -61395477988), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X25.06.15 = structure(c(-61363944088, 
>   -61363942888), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X26.06.15 = structure(c(-61332407188, 
>   -61332407908), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X29.06.15 = structure(c(-61237713148, 
>   -61237713088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.06.15 = structure(c(-61206175588, 
>   -61206176428), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X01.07.15 = structure(c(-62118735268, 
>   -62118734908), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X02.07.15 = structure(c(-62087197588, 
>   -62087197768), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.07.15 = structure(c(-62055662068, 
>   -62055662008), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.07.15 = structure(c(-61960968988, 
>   -61960967008), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X07.07.15 = structure(c(-61929431128, 
>   -61929429868), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X08.07.15 = structure(c(-61897809448, 
>   -61897810528), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.07.15 = structure(c(-61866275548, 
>   -61866271948), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X10.07.15 = structure(c(-61834738228, 
>   -61834735408), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.07.15 = structure(c(-61740042388, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X14.07.15 = structure(c(-61708506448, 
>   -61708504708), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X15.07.15 = structure(c(-61676971168, 
>   -61676971588), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.07.15 = structure(c(-61645347088, 
>   -61645348468), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.07.15 = structure(c(-61519116508, 
>   -61519116928), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X21.07.15 = structure(c(-61487582728, 
>   -61487580628), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X22.07.15 = structure(c(-61456046488, 
>   -61456047688), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.07.15 = structure(c(-61424509768, 
>   -61424511208), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.07.15 = structure(c(-61392889168, 
>   -61392886708), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.07.15 = structure(c(-61298279848, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X28.07.15 = structure(c(-61266656068, 
>   -61266656248), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X29.07.15 = structure(c(-61235121928, 
>   -61235121328), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.07.15 = structure(c(-61203585688, 
>   -61203585388), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X31.07.15 = structure(c(-61172048548, 
>   -61172048308), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.08.15 = structure(c(-62052983428, 
>   -62052983728), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X04.08.15 = structure(c(-62021361268, 
>   -62021360188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X05.08.15 = structure(c(-61989825808, 
>   -61989826528), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.08.15 = structure(c(-61958289448, 
>   -61958288248), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X07.08.15 = structure(c(-61926753748, 
>   -61926753688), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X10.08.15 = structure(c(-61832058088, 
>   -61832060188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X11.08.15 = structure(c(-61800522328, 
>   -61800523168), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X12.08.15 = structure(c(-61768901668, 
>   -61768902388), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.08.15 = structure(c(-61737365188, 
>   -61737365008), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X14.08.15 = structure(c(-61705828408, 
>   -61705829728), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X17.08.15 = structure(c(-61611136168, 
>   -61611134488), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X18.08.15 = structure(c(-61579596508, 
>   -61579599568), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X19.08.15 = structure(c(-61548061168, 
>   -61548063028), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.08.15 = structure(c(-61516439788, 
>   -61516438648), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X21.08.15 = structure(c(-61484903188, 
>   -61484903188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.08.15 = structure(c(-61390208788, 
>   -61390210648), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X25.08.15 = structure(c(-61358673988, 
>   -61358674288), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X26.08.15 = structure(c(-61327137628, 
>   -61327136308), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.08.15 = structure(c(-61295600248, 
>   -61295600548), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X28.08.15 = structure(c(-61263979228, 
>   -61263979408), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X31.08.15 = structure(c(-61169370328, 
>   -61169369428), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X01.09.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -62113375828), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X02.09.15 = structure(c(-62081838988, 
>   -62081841388), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.09.15 = structure(c(-62050306348, 
>   -62050305448), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X04.09.15 = structure(c(-62018682148, 
>   -62018680828), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X07.09.15 = structure(c(-61924073788, 
>   -61924074928), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X08.09.15 = structure(c(-61892450548, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.09.15 = structure(c(-61860914728, 
>   -61860915388), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X10.09.15 = structure(c(-61829380768, 
>   -61829378728), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X11.09.15 = structure(c(-61797844288, 
>   -61797844528), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X14.09.15 = structure(c(-61703149108, 
>   -61703151028), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X15.09.15 = structure(c(-61671612448, 
>   -61671616108), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.09.15 = structure(c(-61639990948, 
>   -61639993648), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X18.09.15 = structure(c(-61576918648, 
>   -61576917988), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X21.09.15 = structure(c(-61482225928, 
>   -61482225028), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X22.09.15 = structure(c(-61450687168, 
>   -61450690708), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.09.15 = structure(c(-61419153028, 
>   -61419152488), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.09.15 = structure(c(-61387530808, 
>   -61387530688), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X25.09.15 = structure(c(-61355994808, 
>   -61355996188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X28.09.15 = structure(c(-61261302328, 
>   -61261299748), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X29.09.15 = structure(c(-61229764948, 
>   -61229764408), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.09.15 = structure(c(-61198228888, 
>   -61198227088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X01.10.15 = structure(c(-62110784908, 
>   -62110784728), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X05.10.15 = structure(c(-61984554688, 
>   -61984554688), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.10.15 = structure(c(-61953019528, 
>   -61953018328), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X07.10.15 = structure(c(-61921484488, 
>   -61921482208), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X08.10.15 = structure(c(-61889861668, 
>   -61889860168), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.10.15 = structure(c(-61858326028, 
>   -61858325608), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X12.10.15 = structure(c(-61763629168, 
>   -61763629348), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.10.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61732093168), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X14.10.15 = structure(c(-61700556868, 
>   -61700557408), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X15.10.15 = structure(c(-61669020868, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.10.15 = structure(c(-61637400208, 
>   -61637398408), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X19.10.15 = structure(c(-61542791908, 
>   -61542791368), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.10.15 = structure(c(-61511169208, 
>   -61511170468), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X21.10.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61479633988), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X22.10.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61448097448), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.10.15 = structure(c(-61416561028, 
>   -61416561628), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X26.10.15 = structure(c(-61321867348, 
>   -61321867468), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.10.15 = structure(c(-61290332908, 
>   -61290329068), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X28.10.15 = structure(c(-61258709008, 
>   -61258709188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X29.10.15 = structure(c(-61227173008, 
>   -61227172888), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.10.15 = structure(c(-61195636948, 
>   -61195637188), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X02.11.15 = structure(c(-62076570748, 
>   -62076570568), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.11.15 = structure(c(-62045033128, 
>   -62045036248), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X04.11.15 = structure(c(-62013413188, 
>   -62013412528), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X05.11.15 = structure(c(-61981874968, 
>   -61981877008), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X06.11.15 = structure(c(-61950339508, 
>   -61950340288), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X12.11.15 = structure(c(-61760951488, 
>   -61760951968), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X13.11.15 = structure(c(-61729417468, 
>   -61729417648), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.11.15 = structure(c(-61634720248, 
>   -61634719888), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X17.11.15 = structure(c(-61603185388, 
>   -61603187248), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X18.11.15 = structure(c(-61571648428, 
>   -61571648608), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X19.11.15 = structure(c(-61540114048, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X20.11.15 = structure(c(-61508490268, 
>   -61508490748), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.11.15 = structure(c(-61413883168, 
>   -61413883348), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.11.15 = structure(c(-61382260288, 
>   -61382262868), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X25.11.15 = structure(c(-61350724348, 
>   -61350725428), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X26.11.15 = structure(c(-61319187328, 
>   -61319186368), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X27.11.15 = structure(c(-61287650968, 
>   -61287651508), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.11.15 = structure(c(-61192957768, 
>   -61192958848), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X01.12.15 = structure(c(-62105516548, 
>   -62105515048), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X02.12.15 = structure(c(-62073978988, 
>   -62073979108), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X03.12.15 = structure(c(-62042442508, 
>   -62042442508), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X04.12.15 = structure(c(-62010820708, 
>   -62010820288), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X07.12.15 = structure(c(-61916214328, 
>   -61916213848), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X08.12.15 = structure(c(-61884590368, 
>   -61884589948), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X09.12.15 = structure(c(-61853054548, 
>   -61853054668), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X10.12.15 = structure(c(-61821519208, 
>   -61821517648), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X11.12.15 = structure(c(-61789982848, 
>   -61789981108), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X14.12.15 = structure(c(-61695287428, 
>   -61695287608), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X15.12.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61663749808), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X16.12.15 = structure(c(-61632127948, 
>   -61632129148), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X17.12.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61600595908), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X18.12.15 = structure(c(NA, 
>   -61569054988), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X21.12.15 = structure(c(-61474363108, 
>   -61474363468), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X22.12.15 = structure(c(-61442826568, 
>   -61442824828), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X23.12.15 = structure(c(-61411289968, 
>   -61411290088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X24.12.15 = structure(c(-61379667748, 
>   NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X28.12.15 = structure(c(-61253437228, 
>   -61253439748), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X29.12.15 = structure(c(-61221901828, 
>   -61221902308), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X30.12.15 = structure(c(-61190366368, 
>   -61190364088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), X31.12.15 = structure(c(-61158829288, 
>   -61158831988), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood the "M" in [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, it is generally better to include code you have already tried. A good question generally includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), **small** sample data, and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: i have  not included any code, in the section this is only the input data. i am new so i am not able to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it is tough to understand your data, given the formatting. Perhaps, if you could post a sample of your data with easy to read formatting. It would be easier for other people to answer.

In general, if you are working with dates, you should try lubridate package. 
Toy example:assuming you have a dataframe df with a date column: date and another column: number which you wish to count

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

month_data <- df %>% group_by(month(date)) %>% summarize(per_month_count = n())
```

You can use other functions like `year()` to extract year, `day()` to extract day from a given date. `month()` also have an optional argument `label` which could be set to `TRUE` if you need month names as output.